# Getting List name in WebPart in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am a beginner to SharePoint development.

I am adding a webpart to a list page. How can I get the name of the list in the webpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When operating in the context of a list, you could use SPContext.Current.List.Title